# How to get know what arguments does pipe transfers in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pipe, pipeline

I have this code in my js file:

```
const read = fs.createReadStream ...
const write = fs.createWriteStream...
```

```
const { pipeline } = require('stream')
...
pipeline(
read,
write,
(error)=>{}
)
```

and i tried like this:

```
read.pipe(write) //what arguments does 'write' get?
```

in both different cases I cant check what arguments are their after stream starts

Thank you!

Comment: Before we get into the details, the `stream` module seems to be a port of native node to the browser, so should you be using this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

In `read.pipe(write)` `write` is an argument to `.pipe()`. It will start streaming the data of the file open with `createReadStream()` to the file specified in `createWriteStream()`.

Doing this with `pipeline` will produce the same effect, but this one automatically handlers errors, and provides you with a callback to let you know when the stream finishes.

If you want to know what is transferred, then you can look at the [stream documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) in Node.JS. To make it simple, it will read [Buffers](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) of 16kb (or 64kb I don't remember well now) from the source file and write them to the destination file. It will start automatically as soon as it can.